# Leaflet Map won't show up - only grey

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, maps, leaflet

So, I have the leaflet map. It was working fine, but somehow it's not working anymore! Can anyone tell me if there is an error in my JS code? Couldn't finde one.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.93985, 6.94013], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 13,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'examples.map-i86knfo3'
}).addTo(map);


L.marker([52.26887, 10.52677]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<b>Design and Data GmbH</b><br/>XY</b><br/>Braunschweig").openPopup();

L.marker([41.87239, 12.48018]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<b>Design and Data GmbH</b><br/>XY</b><br/>Rom").openPopup();

L.marker([50.93985, 6.94013]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<b>Design and Data GmbH</b><br/>Hohenzollernring 56</b><br/>51109 Köln").openPopup();

map.fitBounds([
    [50.93985, 6.94013],
    [52.26887, 10.52677],
    [41.87239, 12.48018]
]);

var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Comment: I have looked over it and compared it to code I've used - sorry, couldn't find a problem w/ your code.  Good luck.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you open your Developer Tools?

Comment: @MarkoLetic No, no errors.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? If so, could you please share it and help others? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think something is wrong with your tileLayer url, I get 404 (Not Found) errors when leaflet is trying to fetch the tiles.

If I change that to use `'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'` the map tiles load correctly.

Comment: Yep, I think mapbox needs an access token.